# Making a quiz game in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I'm trying to make a quizgame in C, I have a file with question and answers formatted like this:

Edinburgh is in which country?;Scotland; Ireland; England;

Each line in the file has a question and three answers, the first answer in the file is always correct. 
I need to use a struct like this:

```
typedef struct{
int answer1;
int answer2;
int answer3;
char*question;
}Questions;
```

I need to get them from a file so I think I should make a loop and something like:

```
Questions q;
for(int i = 0; i < fileLength; i++){
 fscanf(file, "%s%d%d%d", &q.question, &q.answer1,&q.answer2, &q.answer3);
}
```

So I need to loop through the file and make a struct variable for each question and give it the values, and then place it in an array. My teacher told me to use a multi dimensional array, and also pointers. How can I accomplish this in the best way? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you achieved so far ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because clearly a write my code request, not a question.

Comment: I have made a menu, and questions in a file. I just need a way to make the struct variables.

Comment: Please read [Ask] page first. :)

Comment: @SouravGhosh Um, no I just can't figure out how to get the values in the struct variable.

Comment: Assuming that the answers can be any kind of string, you need to use strings for those too.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct Books {
   char  title[50];
   char  author[50];
   char  subject[100];
   int   book_id;
} book;
```

---

```
   struct Books Book1;        /* Declare Book1 of type Book */
   struct Books Book2;        /* Declare Book2 of type Book */

   /* book 1 specification */
   strcpy( Book1.title, "C Programming");
   strcpy( Book1.author, "Nuha Ali"); 
   strcpy( Book1.subject, "C Programming Tutorial");
   Book1.book_id = 6495407;

   /* book 2 specification */
   strcpy( Book2.title, "Telecom Billing");
   strcpy( Book2.author, "Zara Ali");
   strcpy( Book2.subject, "Telecom Billing Tutorial");
   Book2.book_id = 6495700;
```

You first define your struct (like here, at the top),

Then you can use the members as if it was a variable. Kinda like an object

Some ressources :http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_structures.htm

And for some real code :[C, reading from file into structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11280523/c-reading-from-file-into-structure)

Comment: Thanks, I need to get them from a file though. I think I should make a loop 
and use fscanf(file, "%s%d%d%d", Questions.question, Questions.answer1 and so forth

Comment: @Jullix993 Well, the thing is that answering to everything would be like writing a full tutorial... Just try to google with the keywords your giving here : first learn to make and use structs; then learn how files work in C, and maybe some pointers

Comment: @Jullix993 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11280523/c-reading-from-file-into-structure here you go :)