# C - How should I parse tokens from a file into a struct?

Tags: c, file, csv, parsing, struct

I need to parse a csv file directly into a struct. Given that the csv file is something like this:

```
Codice identificativo;Nome;Produttore;Categoria;Prezzo;Eta' minima;

214950;Total War: ROME II;Creative Assembly;Manageriale;54,99;16;
231140;Cities XL Platinum;Focus Home Interactive;Manageriale;14,99;3;
242700;Injustice: Gods Among Us;NetherRealm Studios;Picchiaduro;19,99;16;
244210;Assetto Corsa;Kunos Simulazioni;Racing;29,99;3;
...
```

I wrote this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

...

typedef struct {
    char codice [6];
    char nome [20];
    char produttore [20];
    char categoria [15];
    float prezzo;
    int eta_min;
} Gioco;

...

int main() {
    int max=1, s=0, k=0, n=0;
    Utente registr [max];
    Gioco database [30];
    char cwd[1024], riga [120];
    char* token=NULL;
    FILE* sorgente;

       if ((sorgente=fopen("Database_Videogames.csv", "r"))==NULL) {
          printf ("----------------------------------------- Database_Videogames.csv non trovato! -----------------------------------------\n\n");
          if (getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd))!=NULL) {
              printf("%*sPer caricare il file Database_Videogames.csv, inserirlo nella seguente cartella: %s.\n\n", 26, "", cwd);
          }
       }
       else {
           printf ("------------------------------------------- Database_Videogames.csv trovato! -------------------------------------------\n");
           while(fgets(riga, sizeof (riga), sorgente)) {
                token=strtok(riga, ";");
                strcpy(database[n].codice,token);
                printf("%s\n",database[n].codice);
                token=strtok(NULL, ";");
                strcpy(database[n].nome,token);
                printf("%s\n",database[n].nome);
                token=strtok(NULL, ";");
                strcpy(database[n].produttore,token);
                printf("%s\n",database[n].produttore);
                token=strtok(NULL, ";");
                strcpy(database[n].categoria,token);
                printf("%s\n",database[n].categoria);
                token=strtok(NULL, ";");
                database[n].prezzo=atof(token);
                printf("%f\n",database[n].prezzo);
                token=strtok(NULL, ";\n");
                database[n].eta_min=atoi(token);
                printf("%d\n",database[n].eta_min);
                n++;
          }
          fclose(sorgente);
          printf("\n\n\n");
          ...
```

But the program crashes when I execute it, with this written text:

```
------------------------------------------- Database_Videogames.csv trovato! -------------------------------------------

´╗┐Codice identificativo
Nome
Produttore
Categoria
0.000000
0
```

Moreover, I don't wanna read the first line of the file at all, should I use a for cycle to do so?

Comment: `char codice [6];` --> `char codice [6+1];` : +1 for null-terminator. Also skip first line.

Comment: try to use fscanf f
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11280523/c-reading-from-file-into-structure

Comment: You do not check the result of strtok either. It will return null if there are no more tokens left - which might happen if your csv file does not provide all columns (bad format...) or if your line buffer is too short to hold the entire line.

Comment: @jrrossicardoso fscanf can get you into trouble - it is often better to read entire lines at once (fgets) and then use **s**scanf...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much of the problem is that you do not allow enough memory for some fields and that will cause problems when using `strcpy`. Protect against that by using `strncpy`. This code also tests to see if there is enough space for each field.
`strtok` can be used but if there is any chance that there may be consecutive delimiters it is better to use something else such as `strpbrk`.
Using `strpbrk` and two pointers will let you traverse through each line of the file and extract each field. If a delimiter is not found, `srtpbrk` will return NULL. That problem can be handled in a number of ways. This simply continues the loop ignoring the problem line of text.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

typedef struct {
    char codice [10];
    char nome [30];
    char produttore [30];
    char categoria [30];
    float prezzo;
    int eta_min;
} Gioco;

int main(void) {
    int  n=0;
    int  each=0;
    int  span=0;
    Gioco database [30];
    char cwd[1024], riga [120];
    char* start = NULL;
    char* end = NULL;
    char* comma = NULL;
    FILE* sorgente;

    if ((sorgente=fopen("Database_Videogames.csv", "r"))==NULL) {
        printf ("----------------------------------------- Database_Videogames.csv non trovato! -----------------------------------------\n\n");
        if (getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd))!=NULL) {
            printf("%*sPer caricare il file Database_Videogames.csv, inserirlo nella seguente cartella: %s.\n\n", 26, "", cwd);
        }
    }
    else {
        printf ("------------------------------------------- Database_Videogames.csv trovato! -------------------------------------------\n");

        fgets(riga, sizeof (riga), sorgente);//read first line and ignore

        while(fgets(riga, sizeof (riga), sorgente)) {
            start = riga;
            end = strpbrk ( start, ";");//find the next ;
            if ( !end) {
                continue;//handle the problem
            }
            span = ( end - start);//get span of characters between ;
            if ( span > sizeof ( database[n].codice)) {
                span = sizeof ( database[n].codice);//make sure not to exceed size of array
            }
            strncpy ( database[n].codice, start, span);
            database[n].codice[span] = '\0';

            start = end + 1;



            end = strpbrk ( start, ";");//find the next ;
            if ( !end) {
                continue;//handle the problem
            }
            span = ( end - start);//get span of characters between ;
            if ( span > sizeof ( database[n].nome)) {
                span = sizeof ( database[n].nome);//make sure not to exceed size of array
            }
            strncpy ( database[n].nome, start, span);
            database[n].nome[span] = '\0';

            start = end + 1;



            end = strpbrk ( start, ";");//find the next ;
            if ( !end) {
                continue;//handle the problem
            }
            span = ( end - start);//get span of characters between ;
            if ( span > sizeof ( database[n].produttore)) {
                span = sizeof ( database[n].produttore);//make sure not to exceed size of array
            }
            strncpy ( database[n].produttore, start, span);
            database[n].produttore[span] = '\0';

            start = end + 1;



            end = strpbrk ( start, ";");//find the next ;
            if ( !end) {
                continue;//handle the problem
            }
            span = ( end - start);//get span of characters between ;
            if ( span > sizeof ( database[n].categoria)) {
                span = sizeof ( database[n].categoria);//make sure not to exceed size of array
            }
            strncpy ( database[n].categoria, start, span);
            database[n].categoria[span] = '\0';

            start = end + 1;


            end = strpbrk ( start, ";\n");//find the next ; or \n
            if ( !end) {
                continue;//handle the problem
            }


            comma = strpbrk ( start, ",");//find a comma
            if ( comma && comma < end) {
                *comma = '.';//change comma to dot
            }

            database[n].prezzo = 0.0f;
            database[n].eta_min = 0;

            if ( EOF == sscanf ( start, "%f%n", &database[n].prezzo, &span)) {
                break;//handle the problem
            }

            start = end + 1;

            if ( EOF == sscanf ( start, "%d%n", &database[n].eta_min, &span)) {
                break;//handle the problem
            }

            n++;
            if ( n >= 30) {
                break;
            }
        }
        fclose(sorgente);
        printf("\n\n\n");
    }
    while ( each < n) {
        printf ( "n %d\n codice %s\n nome %s\n produttore %s\n categoria %s\n prezzo %f\n eta_min %d\n"
        , each
        , database[each].codice
        , database[each].nome
        , database[each].produttore
        , database[each].categoria
        , database[each].prezzo
        , database[each].eta_min);
        each++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is a option using [Jonathan Leffler's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44764336/c-how-should-i-parse-tokens-from-a-file-into-a-struct/44768709#comment76518955_44768709) comment.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

typedef struct {
    char codice [10];
    char nome [30];
    char produttore [30];
    char categoria [30];
    float prezzo;
    int eta_min;
} Gioco;

char *extractstr ( char * source, char *target, int max);
char *extractfloat ( char * source, float *targetfloat);
char *extractint ( char * source, int *targetint);

int main(void) {
    int  n=0;
    int  each=0;
    Gioco database [30];
    char cwd[1024], riga [120];
    char* start = NULL;
    FILE* sorgente;

    if ((sorgente=fopen("Database_Videogames.csv", "r"))==NULL) {
        printf ("----------------------------------------- Database_Videogames.csv non trovato! -----------------------------------------\n\n");
        if (getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd))!=NULL) {
            printf("%*sPer caricare il file Database_Videogames.csv, inserirlo nella seguente cartella: %s.\n\n", 26, "", cwd);
        }
    }
    else {
        printf ("------------------------------------------- Database_Videogames.csv trovato! -------------------------------------------\n");

        fgets(riga, sizeof (riga), sorgente);//read first line and ignore

        while(fgets(riga, sizeof (riga), sorgente)) {
            start = riga;
            start = extractstr ( start, database[n].codice, sizeof ( database[n].codice));
            if ( !( *start)) {
                continue;//handle the problem
            }

            start = extractstr ( start, database[n].nome, sizeof ( database[n].nome));
            if ( !( *start)) {
                continue;//handle the problem
            }

            start = extractstr ( start, database[n].produttore, sizeof ( database[n].produttore));
            if ( !( *start)) {
                continue;//handle the problem
            }

            start = extractstr ( start, database[n].categoria, sizeof ( database[n].categoria));
            if ( !( *start)) {
                continue;//handle the problem
            }

            start = extractfloat ( start, &database[n].prezzo);
            if ( !( *start)) {
                continue;//handle the problem
            }

            start = extractint ( start, &database[n].eta_min);

            n++;
            if ( n >= 30) {
                break;
            }
        }
        fclose(sorgente);
        printf("\n\n\n");
    }
    while ( each < n) {
        printf ( "n %d\n codice %s\n nome %s\n produttore %s\n categoria %s\n prezzo %f\n eta_min %d\n"
        , each
        , database[each].codice
        , database[each].nome
        , database[each].produttore
        , database[each].categoria
        , database[each].prezzo
        , database[each].eta_min);
        each++;
    }
    return 0;
}

char *extractstr ( char * source, char *target, int max) {
    char *semicolon = NULL;
    int span = 0;

    semicolon = strpbrk ( source, ";");//find the next ;
    if ( !semicolon) {
        return source + 1;//handle the problem
    }
    span = ( semicolon - source);//get span of characters between ;
    if ( span > max) {
        span = max;//make sure not to exceed size of array
    }
    strncpy ( target, source, span);
    target[span] = '\0';

    return semicolon + 1;
}

char *extractfloat ( char * source, float *targetfloat) {
    char *semicolon = NULL;
    char *comma = NULL;

    semicolon = strpbrk ( source, ";");//find the next ;
    if ( !semicolon) {
        return source + 1;//handle the problem
    }
    comma = strpbrk ( source, ",");//find comma
    if ( comma && comma < semicolon) {
        *comma = '.';//change comma to dot
    }
    *targetfloat = 0.0f;

    sscanf ( source, "%f", targetfloat);

    return semicolon + 1;
}

char *extractint ( char * source, int *targetint) {
    char *semicolon = NULL;

    semicolon = strpbrk ( source, ";\n");//find the next ; or \n
    if ( !semicolon) {
        return source + 1;//handle the problem
    }
    *targetint = 0;

    sscanf ( source, "%d", targetint);

    return semicolon + 1;
}
```

Comment: Comment: the floating point data in the question uses comma `,` rather than dot `.` as the decimal point.  In the standard C locale (read American), your code to analyze the last two fields would treat the digits after the decimal point (comma) as the `eta_min` field.  It might be better to continue to extract the fields based on the semicolon separator and then call a function to convert the string (or range of characters) to a floating point value. I think I'd be looking to create a function to handle the string fields too to avoid so much repetition in the existing function. That's harder.

Comment: But, just in case you're in doubt, what I see (I haven't tested it) looks good — it would plausibly work and deals with some issues that the original did not.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a repetition to break each line with token=strtok(riga, "\n"); and then do another repetition to break every information between ';' with token=strtok(NULL, ";");