# Reading from file into structure using a cycle and pointers

Tags: c

I have a text documet which has the following data

```
$
osobny automobil
Ferrari
Autobazar Pestovatelska 4 Bratislava
68957
2012
udrziavane cervene dvojdverove
$
kamion
Renault magnum
AUTO Modranska 5 Senec
28000
2016
po havarii opraveny v dobrom stave
$
karavan
Kostitras
JANA, Vitanova 147
20250
2010
Voz na dovolenku
```

The structure looks like this:

```
typedef struct auta {  
    char kategoria [50];  
    char znacka [50];
    char predajca [100];
    int cena;
    int rok_vyroby;
    char stav_vozidla [200];
    struct auta *dalsi;
}AUTA;
```

And the thing my fucntion is supposed to do is read from this file a printf the number of entries. For example $ counts as one entry, so there would be three entries total. I have found it quite stupid to do this entry by entry with a different structure pointer as i am doing it now but the problem is i dont know how to make a sensible loop. What i have so far is how i read the first entry from the file.

```
AUTA *p=NULL;
p=(AUTA*)malloc(sizeof(AUTA));
    fgets(z[0],5,fr);
    fgets(p->kategoria,50,fr);
    fgets(p->znacka,50,fr);
    fgets(p->predajca,100,fr);
    fscanf(fr,"%d",&p->cena);
    fscanf(fr,"%d\n",&p->rok_vyroby);
    fgets(p->stav_vozidla,200,fr);
```

So the question would be how to load entries from the text file into the structure using a loop.

Comment: Using a _cycle_? Do you mean a loop?

Comment: Yes i do sorry.

Comment: Did you try something with `while`?

Comment: Here's a nice example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11280523/c-reading-from-file-into-structure

Comment: Im having a little trouble understanding with a whole structure of pointers there so i thought maybe i could use just one or two pointers and make do with that but i havent quite figured that out.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what language this is, but I'll assume that dalsi translates to next (if not, add a `struct auta *next` at the end of the structure).   I'm also assuming you're a beginner so I'll go over some of what I'm doing below:

```
AUTA *pStart = NULL;   // keep track of start of list:
AUTA **pp = &pStart;   // set a pointer to the pointer of the active entry

while (!feof(fr)) {
    fgets(z[0],5,fr);
    if (feof(fr))
           break;
    if (strcmp(z[0],"$") != 0) 
           continue;   // non $ sign -- not start of record... ignore line
    // allocate record:
    *pp = malloc(AUTA*)malloc(sizeof(AUTA))
    if (*pp == NULL) {   // double check that malloc succeeded
        sprintf(stderr, "Out of memory\n"); 
        exit -1;
    }
    // read in record -- note pp points to the pointer to the 
    // record, so you want to access (*pp)-> ...
    fgets((*pp)->kategoria,50,fr);
    fgets((*pp)->znacka,50,fr);
    fgets((*pp)->predajca,100,fr);
    fscanf(fr,"%d",&(*pp)->cena);
    fscanf(fr,"%d\n",&(*pp)->rok_vyroby);
    fgets((*pp)->stav_vozidla,200,fr);
    (*pp)->dalsi = NULL;   // in case this is the last entry...
    pp = &(*pp)->dalsi;
}
```

This solution used double indirection (a pointer to a pointer), which is a bit to take in if you're new.   I would suggest drawing a diagram if you're having trouble getting your head around it.   Basically, we start with a pointer to the first record (`pStart`).   `pStart` starts off as `NULL`.  You then have a pointer to the pointer to the first entry (that is, `pp` points to `pStart`.  You then start looping.   If you find a `$`, you start reading.  First, you allocate memory for a new record and set `*pp` to point to that (remember that `pp` pointed to `pStart`, ergo now `*pp` or `pStart` points to the new record.   You then scan in that record.   When you're done, you set `pp` to point to the next pointer (`dalsi`) of the current record, and loop.  The second iteration of the loop will populate `pStart->dalsi` to point to the next record, so you end up with:

```
 pStart ------> (record1)     +---> (record2)    +---> (record3)
                  \ dalsi  ---+       \dalsi  ---+         \dalsi --> NULL
```

Comment: Just make sure you understand it.    This sounds like a homework assignment, and the last thing I want to do is to get you out of having to learn something :-)

Comment: Concerning `while (!feof(fr)) {`, review [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: Certinaly `fgets(z[0],5,fr); if (strcmp(z,"$")...` is broken code.  `z[0]` de-references the pointer.

Comment: Thanks @chux -- sorry, a bit hastily written.    OP quoted the check against `z[0]`, not sure if they mean `&z[0]`, but I'll assume it's a pointer to an array of strings.   For the `feof` issue, I created another test after trying to read the `$`.

Comment: Checking `feof()` makes most sense _after_ receiving an end-of-file/error indication from `fgets()`.  Rather than `fgets(....); ... if (feof(...)) done()`, use `if(fgets(...) == NULL) done();`