# Read text from phone book list and add to a structure

Tags: c, io, structure

I am attempting to read from file "pb_List.txt" that contains:

> John:789-654-3210
>   Bill:852-123-4567
>   Amy:963-321-0000

I need to add the name and number contents to a phone book structure "pb"

```
struct phonebook{
    char name[value_size];
    char phone[value_size];
}

struct phonebook pb[book_size];
```

UPDATE:

```
void addFile(){
    File *pb_List;
    pb_List = fopen("pb_List.txt", "r");

    char name[value_size];
    char phone[value_size];

    fscanf(pb_List, "%s %s", name, phone);
    strcpy(pb[size].name, name);
    strcpy(pb[size].phone, phone);
    size++
 }
```

I was able to add the first line, but my function obviously doesn't iterate to the next line. How would my while loop look for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C, reading from file into structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11280523/c-reading-from-file-into-structure)

Comment: Use `fread`, `fgets`,  `fgetc`, `getchar`, or `getc`.  Then parse the data.

Comment: Since the name and the number are delimited by a colon ':' you can copy all characters up to the colon into `name` and everything after that into `phone`.

Comment: After reading a line with `fgets`, you can use `strtok` to split the string at the colon, and `strcpy` to copy the strings into the struct.

Answer (score 1):

So I ended up wanting to continue writing an almost full program to your problem. Thus, I updated this answer with a full example of how to use my original answer in a program. Below the code of my original answer is the actual code of a working program.

For your code, I don't think the "phonebook"'s name and phone should be an array but should be a pointer to arrays of chars. That is because if you have a large program even if you give a size that is always bigger than the necessary size or working with a version of "c" that allows dynamic array allocation at runtime, you can run into the problem of running out of stack memory.

Nonetheless, this code below is an example and is for parsing just one line. In a real usage case, you would have to modify the code properly to use it in a loop. For the routines, you just look for the ":" location. If you found that then look for the null char(end of string) location. I did place comments in the code, thus, I am not going to explain much here.

Also, you should give consideration to letting pb be dynamic with calloc() and realloc(). Also, calloc() and realloc() do not always work. You can also, use malloc() but you have to inject the null char by yourself.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h> 

struct phonebook{
    char * name;
    char * phone;
};

int main(void) {
  char * line = "John:789-654-3210";
  char c;

  // search for the :
  struct phonebook pb[1];
  int dotloc = -1;
  int endloc = 0;
  int recordIndex = 0;

  // Find the dot first
  // and then end line.
  // This could be done in one loop
  // But split into two 
  for ( int i = 0; ; i++) {
    if( line[i] == ':' ) {
      dotloc = i;
      break;
    }
    if( line[i] == '\0' ) break;
  }

  // If found : then that is valid
  if ( dotloc > -1 ){
    for( int i = dotloc + 1; ; i++){
      if( line[i] == '\0' ){
        endloc = i;
        break;  
      }
    }

    // Positioning
    // If : is at pos, there is 5 char in the string
    // add + for null char.
    // If : is at 0 there isn't a char but when calloc still need one for the null char. Empty string.
    pb[recordIndex].name = (char*) calloc(dotloc + 1, sizeof(char));

    // If : is at 5 and end is at 10, there is only 4 char in between but add keep five because of end char.
    pb[recordIndex].phone = (char*) calloc(endloc - dotloc, sizeof(char));

    // Memory allocation fail.
    // Do something else.
    if( pb[recordIndex].name == NULL ) return 1;
    if( pb[recordIndex].phone == NULL ) return 1;

    // copy from line[0] to dotloc location as how many chars.
    // if dotloc is 0, nothing will be copy.
    // null char is already appended by calloc.
    memcpy(pb[recordIndex].name, line, dotloc * sizeof(char));

    // copy from the location of where dotloc is plus 1
    // how many char is base on where endloc is - dotloc 
    // -1
    // If endloc at 1 and dot loc is at 0(next to), nothing to be copy.
    memcpy(pb[recordIndex].phone, &line[dotloc + 1], (endloc - dotloc - 1));
    recordIndex++;
  }

  printf("%s\n", pb[0].name);
  printf("%s", pb[0].phone);

  // Sometimes you need to free memory properly.
  // depend on which system you target or your use case.
  free(pb[0].name);
  free(pb[0].phone);
  return 0;
}
```

I won't give much explanation into what each function in the program does, as the key point already mentioned above and that can take hours to write. This program below to demonstrate how to utilize my original answer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h> 

struct phoneRecord{
    char * name;
    char * phone;
};

struct phoneBook{
    struct phoneRecord * record;
    int length;
    int size;
};

struct phoneBook newBook(){
    // change init_size to 1 for debugging
    int init_size = 30;
    static size_t recordSize = sizeof(struct phoneRecord);
    struct phoneBook output;

    output.record = (struct phoneRecord*) malloc( init_size * recordSize);
    output.length = 0;
    output.size = init_size;

    return output;
}

void freeBook( struct phoneBook * pb){
    for ( int i = 0; i < pb->length; i++ ){
        free(pb->record[i].name);
        free(pb->record[i].phone);
    }
    free(pb->record);
    pb->record = NULL;
    pb->length = 0;
    pb->size = 0;
}

// 0 for success
// 1 for error
int increaseBookSize(struct phoneBook * pb){
    if ( pb == NULL ) return 1;
    static size_t recordSize = sizeof(struct phoneRecord);
    const int newSize = pb->size * 2;
    if ( newSize == 0 ) return 1;

    struct phoneRecord * tempPointer = (struct phoneRecord*) realloc(pb->record, newSize * recordSize);

    if ( tempPointer != NULL ) {
        pb->record = tempPointer;
        pb->size = newSize;
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

// Return - 1 for error.
// Return 0 for no record found or no dot.
// Return 1 for record found.
int getRecord( const char * line, struct phoneRecord * pr){
  // Null check
  if ( pr == NULL ) return -1;

  int dotloc = -1;
  int endloc = 0;

  for ( int i = 0; ; i++) {
    if( line[i] == ':' ) {
      dotloc = i;
      break;
    }
    if( line[i] == '\0' ) break;
  }

  if ( dotloc > -1 ){
    for( int i = dotloc + 1; ; i++){
      if( line[i] == '\0' ){
        endloc = i;
        break;  
      }
    }

    pr->name = (char*) calloc(dotloc + 1, sizeof(char));
    pr->phone = (char*) calloc(endloc - dotloc, sizeof(char));

    if( pr->name == NULL ) return -1;
    if( pr->phone == NULL ) return -1;

    memcpy(pr->name, line, dotloc * sizeof(char));

    memcpy(pr->phone, &line[dotloc + 1], (endloc - dotloc - 1));
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}

int main(void) {
    struct phoneBook pb = newBook();
    const char * fileName = "test.txt";
    char * line = NULL;
    FILE *fp;
    size_t len = 0;
    int recordReturnCode;

    fp = fopen(fileName, "r");
    if (fp == NULL){
        printf("Couldn't open file %s.\n", fileName);
        return 1;
    }

    while (getline(&line, &len, fp) != -1) {
        if ( pb.length >= pb.size ) { 
            if ( increaseBookSize(&pb) != 0 ) {
                printf("Something is wrong with getting more memory for the book. However, still print out what already got.\n");
                break;
            }
        }
        recordReturnCode = getRecord(line, &pb.record[pb.length]);

        if ( recordReturnCode == 1 ) pb.length++;
        if ( recordReturnCode == -1 ){
            printf("Something is wrong with getting the record. Clean up and exit.\n");
            freeBook(&pb);
            free(line);
            return 1;
        }
    }
    free(line);

    printf("Print phonebook size for debuging. Size: %d\n", pb.size);
    printf("Read file '%s' and found %d records. Printing each record.\n\n", fileName, pb.length);

    for ( int i = 0; i < pb.length; i++ ){
        printf("Record: %d | Name: %s | Phone: %s", i, pb.record[i].name, pb.record[i].phone);
    }

    freeBook(&pb);
    printf("\n\nChecking book after free. Length: %d, Size: %d", pb.length, pb.size);
    if ( pb.record == NULL ) printf("\nPhonebook free properly, record is NULL.");
    return 0;
}
```

test.txt content:

```
John:789-654-3210
Bill:852-123-4567
This is not a valid record
Amy:963-321-0000

AfterEmpty:123-456-789
:###-###-####
noNumber:
Kevin:123-123-1234
```