# Struct Array and File

Tags: arrays, c

Actually, I need to calculate course average of student, for example course 115: grades are 86.5 and 84.3, so average is 85.4.
Therefore I need to read data from file and store it in array but I don't understand how to do so without using pointers apart from FILE pointer.

There is following data in the file: studentid, courseid, grade 
Input file "input.txt":

```
201456 115 86.5
201456 112 86.4
201456 122 85.4
202145 115 84.3
202145 112 65.3
202145 122 78.4
```

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct{
    int courseid;
    double courseavg;
} Course;

typedef struct {
    int studentid;
    double grade[3];
} Student;

typedef struct {
    Course course[3];
    Student student[2];
} Major;

int main() {
    Course course[3] = {
                {1, 0.0},
                {2, 0.0},
                {3, 0.0}
        };
        
        Student student[2] = {
                {0, 0.0, {0.0, 0.0, 0.0}}, 
                {0, 0.0, {0.0, 0.0, 0.0}}
        };

    FILE *in = fopen("input.txt", "r");

    fscanf(in,"%d %d %f %d %d %f %d %d %f %d %d %f %d %d %f %d %d %f",
            &student[0].studentid, &course[0].courseid, &student[0].grade[0],
            &student[0].studentid, &course[1].courseid, &student[0].grade[1],
            &student[0].studentid, &course[2].courseid, &student[0].grade[2],
            &student[1].studentid, &course[0].courseid, &student[1].grade[0],
            &student[1].studentid, &course[1].courseid, &student[1].grade[1],
            &student[1].studentid, &course[2].courseid, &student[1].grade[2]);

    course[0].courseavg = (student[0].grade[0] + student[1].grade[0])/2;
    printf("%f", &course[0].courseavg);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11280523/c-reading-from-file-into-structure

Comment: Be aware that nobody will write your code for you here. You need to come up with some cod

Comment: Yeah, I understand this.

Comment: @Rosaline you code may be correct and if may work as expected. But it will work only if the number of lines in your text file is _exactly_ 6. I'm pretty sure your code should be more flexible.

Comment: Answering this question would require an extensive amount of explaining and writing. You shouldn't hardcode the logic like you have in your post. Instead, you should process each line of the file independently. There is also the question of whether the maximum number of students should be dynamic or fixed.

Comment: Have a look at `fgets()` and `sscanf()` that should give you a pretty good starting point.

Comment: A working program could look something like this: 1. initialize data 2. open file 3. read file line by line (and process the line) 5. examine data and calculate average

Answer (score 2):

You need to read the file line by line and process each line independently:

```
#include <stdlib.h> // EXIT_FAILURE
#include <stdio.h> // fopen()
#include <stdbool.h> // bool

/**
 * Struct that holds evaluation of a student.
 */
struct StudentEvaluation {
    int student_id;
    int course_id;
    float grade;
};

/**
 * Function responsible for parsing a single line.
 */
bool processLineBuffer(
    const char *line,
    struct StudentEvaluation *eval
) {
    // sscanf returns the number of items it
    // successfully parsed
    int ret = sscanf(
         line,
        "%d %d %f",
        &eval->student_id, &eval->course_id, &eval->grade
    );

    // that's why we check if the return value is 3
    return ret == 3;
}

int main(void) {
    FILE *fp = fopen("students.txt", "r");

    if (!fp) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open file.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    char line_buffer[256];

    while (fgets(line_buffer, sizeof(line_buffer), fp)) {
        struct StudentEvaluation eval;

        // only examine StudentEvaluation if parsing was successful
        if (processLineBuffer(line_buffer, &eval)) {
            printf("successfully parsed: \n");

            // print the parsed data:
            printf("    student_id is %d\n", eval.student_id);
            printf("    course_id is %d\n", eval.course_id);
            printf("    grade is %f\n", eval.grade);
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);
}
```

This is of course by no means the complete program, but it should give you a framework to (hopefully) complete your program.